# What's the programmability function for setting visibility on jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I tried this code, visible being a parameter of function:

```
$('#something').show(isVisible);
```

THat's not working though, must evaluate:

```
if (isVisible) 
    $('#something').show();
else
    $('#something').hide();
```

Comment: you probably meant `if (!isVisible) `

Comment: it's correct `if (isVisible)`

Comment: @Hao that does not mean the same thing

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin i'm referring to my post(correct), not his `if (!isVisible)`

Comment: Your post is incorrect. @gdoron is correct.

Comment: How do you get the `isVisible` value?

Comment: I think the `isVisible` variable is badly named: it should be `setToVisible` or similar. That is, OP wants to show the "#something" element if that variable is true. (It has nothing to do with the current state of the element.)

Comment: @nnnnnn `function hideTab(tabName,isVisible) { $('#tabList').filter('[tabname=' + tabname + ']').toggle(isVisible); }`. isVisible is a good name(at least on java or other languages' naming convention), setToVisible sounds like a verb

Comment: I think a verb is more appropriate, including in Java. The parameter is a flag telling the function what to do...

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin i don't get it what's incorrect on my post :-)

Comment: @Hao. you can see how many people got confused because of the name. so I would say the "verb" option is a lot better. "isVisible" means is it visible now.

Comment: meant `showTab(tabName,isVisible)` here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295221/whats-the-programmability-function-for-setting-visibility-on-jquery#comment13247761_10295221)

Comment: I don't see any confusion there. I agree it should be a verb if it is for the method name, but if it is a parameter name it should not be a verb e.g. `JFrame: setVisible(boolean visible)` http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFramesetVisiblebooleanvisible.htm You won't see an API named like this `void setVisible(boolean setVisible)`. isn't it? It's rather `void setVisible(boolean visible)` or `void setVisible(boolean isVisible)`

Comment: The example from your last comment is more likely to be `setVisibility(boolean visible)`. I've never seen a Java method that used `isSomething` in a parameter name. Of course you are free to name your methods and parameters however you see fit, but if you expect other people to use your code without confusion - well, as you've already seen _everybody_ got confused by the code in your question...

Comment: Well we could also argue that *everybody* can get confused by `setVisible` as a parameter name too. At least I don't use `setSomething` as a convention for parameter name nor variable name, there could be more confusion that could arise on `setSomething` as the name of the parameter/variable than the one that uses `isSomething`. `setSomething` is for method. I`d seen many codes that uses `isSomething` convention for parameter or variable name, ex: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.3/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/scoping/featurecalls/DefaultJvmFeatureDescriptionProvider.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = ['show', 'hide'];
$('#something')[arr[isVisible & 1]]();
```

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the evaluation, eliminating the `if` statement

Comment: This answer just repeats the code already proposed in the question, except getting the hide and show backwards.

Comment: accepted for showing some innate quality of javascript :-) might use this

Comment: Really? Do you really think it's the best way to go?

Comment: @gdoron dont think so.. but an alternative way to make OP's wish true :(

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#something').toggle(isVisible);
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

`.toggle( showOrHide )`

> showOrHide A Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements

Comment: i'm trying to achieve it programatically, passing the isVisible parameter to the method. not necessarily toggling it

Comment: @Hao - `$('#something').toggle(isVisible)` is exactly what you are looking for. It toggles if you don't pass any parameters, but if you pass a boolean it works how you want it to. Read the doco gdoron linked to.

Comment: @nnnnnn. I added the relevant doc to my answer. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @nnnnnn you put your comment in an answer, i'll upvote it. i tried `show(variableHere)` rather than `toggle(variableHere)`. didn't know toggle accepts parameter. thanks :-)

Comment: @Hao - no need for that, gdoron's answer covers it.

Comment: @nnnnnn it's nice of you :-) it's you who pointed things out to the right direction though. i would rather upvote you if your comment is in answer